# Most efficient way to query Data Store in App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a data store with about 150,000 entities in it. When I query the store using filters, my queries are REALLY slow. My structure is completely flat, i.e. every entity is a sibling of every other.

1: Is it better to use GQL instead of filters?

2: Is this not the best use-case for Data Store, and should I use a SQL database instead?

Here's an example of my code:

```
// Look for a buy opportunity
dateFilter = new FilterPredicate("date", FilterOperator.EQUAL, dt);
scoreFilter = new FilterPredicate("score", FilterOperator.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL, 10.0);
safetyFilter = new FilterPredicate("score", FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL, -1.0);
mainFilter = CompositeFilterOperator.and(dateFilter,scoreFilter,safetyFilter);
q = new Query("StockEntity",stockKey).setFilter(mainFilter);
q.addSort("score", Query.SortDirection.ASCENDING);

stocks = datastore.prepare(q).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(availableSlots));
```

Some more details:

1. 150,000ish records, divided amongst 500 stocks, so about 300 records per stock, one for each day in a date range.
2. Query like that above, where a specific date is passed in, and the 500 stocks are effectively filtered based on a 'score', with the number of records desired to return is between 10 and 20 takes upwards of 30 seconds to complete, on my development machine.

Haven't tried pushing to production yet, but I guess I will try that next -- I figured that there wouldn't be a huge difference. My dev machine is quite a high spec iMac.

Comment: Gql and filters do the same thing.  You need to look at your data and look for ways of optimizing it for your queries.

Comment: How does one optimize in an environment like Datastore? I'm used to using SQL/Indexes etc.

Data object is very simple:
    Stock Ticker:String
    Close Price:Double
    Score:Double
    Date:String

...and I have about 150k records that look like that.

Comment: You need to give us a bit more information, such as how many records you are returning, how often is the query run, do the parameters change.  Most datastore optimizations revolve around preprocessing at write time, denormalizing data, caching frequent queries.  On the face of it this query should be fast, but if you are trying to retrieve large numbers of records then you will hit performance walls.

Comment: You should also qualify "really slow" do you mean slow in dev or production, what sort of measured time etc..

Comment: Thanks Tim -- details added to the Q.

Comment: can also add the composite index(should be auto generated in your dev server) being used for executing this query

Comment: Don't assume that the dev environment runs anything like production.  The underlying datastore implementations are different.  You may find some things faster locally (compute) and other things slower - datastore operations on large datasets for instance.

Comment: Do check your indexes but I would guess the query wouldn't even work without them.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Restrictions_on_queries

> Inequality filters are limited to at most one property
>
> To avoid having to scan the entire index table, the query mechanism
>   relies on all of a query's potential results being adjacent to one
>   another in the index. To satisfy this constraint, a single query may
>   not use inequality comparisons (LESS_THAN, LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL,
>   GREATER_THAN, GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL, NOT_EQUAL) on more than one
>   property across all of its filters. For example, the following query
>   is valid, because both inequality filters apply to the same property:

Short answer is that you really can't quite do what you want with data store.

Comment: Have another good look, he's not using inequality comparisons on more than one property.

Comment: Whoops.  I swear that second one said safety in the field name.

Answer (score 0):

First up, that query will run faster on the actual Datastore.

1. Using GQL or Filters is basically the same.
2. When using the Datastore you should first define the functionality you need. For example: You want to show a list of stocks with a specific order and filters. Now look at any other views of the same data that your app needs. Then decide how the data should be structured.

This is very different from an RDBMS where the database can often accommodate most functionality without changing the data model and the data is modeled in a more 'generic' way (normalization).

In general, the Datastore's read performance will be optimal if you know the KEY of whatever it is you want to read and it will perform at it's worst when doing queries since that always requires an index 'scan'.

Knowing this, I tend to use the Ancestor relationship often. Requesting the 'children' of an Ancestor seems to perform better and is Consistent. For example, I use a query like:

```
SELECT * WHERE ANCESTOR IS {key}
```

Where {key} is the key of the ancestor (or 'parent'). This query returns the ancestor entity and all entities that have this ancestor key in their paths. On rare occasions I use one of the filters as a parent 'value' to group objects but be careful, a key is not changeable once the entity is written (you can change the key, but it will result in a copy).

Also, if you know the average size of a 'set'. For example, Orderlines that belong to an Order. You could choose to keep track of each Orderline key somewhere. Requesting the first 20 keys in a batched read is a fast operation. This is basically the same as indexing, however the ordering and filtering could be done at 'write time' so your list only contains keys that match your filters.

Avoid creating views that allow users to 'dynamically' select filters.

How to optimize further: 
1. Use denormalization to minimize the number of lookups or queries.
2. Cache (Memcache) where you can.